# How to add your own control in windows right click menu?

Tags: c#, windows

I want to add a control to windows right click menu. I make a program that take folder path and then arrange that folder's file. But i want my control shown in windows right click menu so that if i click that it run my program with argument(address of that folder). Is it possible?? if please tell me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at [this article](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=ShellExtensions).

It takes an in-depth look at the COM infrastructure surrounding the shell right-click menu, and then shows you how to hook it all up in managed code via interop.